# Can I use Flatiron's resourceful in express?

Tags: node.js, express, flatiron.js

Is it possible to use Flatiron's resourcefull (ODM) in express.js?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Yes.**

You'll want to use express's resource router project, https://github.com/visionmedia/express-resource/. This will require a little bit of setup since you'll need to map each resourceful method call.

I would recommend looking at Flatiron's resource router https://github.com/flatiron/restful, since it requires zero-configuration for working with Resourceful resources.

Comment: Very nice! I did not realize they had already done all the glue work.

Comment: Restful isn't completed, it won't accept or return a full record through to/from resourceful. which is sad, because restful and resourceful are basically the only two packages that can be used in any nodejs project that utilises the http package. every other approach tries to do too much and restricts your integration options.

Answer (score 3):

There's nothing in Resourceful that is specific to any other package; the readme at https://github.com/flatiron/resourceful does a good job of showing how you would use this package in *any* project (not just Express-based ones).